# Insert video using <object> element

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm new to HTML and need to insert a video from youtube onto my page using an  element. I've tried different ways but just cannot get it to work. This is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSM3w1v-A_Y

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML> 
<head> <title> video </title> </head>
<body>
  <object> </object>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: The only way (other than downloading the video and serving it yourself) to display a video from YouTube on your website is to use an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp). YouTube actually provides the code required to you. If you open any video you can right click on it and click "Copy embed code". The iframe will be copied to your clipboard and you can paste it into your website.

Comment: Yea, the assignment said to use the <object> element to do this though.

Comment: Okay. You mentioned you tried a couple things. Could you include that in your question as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You should also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/10601203) for more information on how to improve your question. Narrow it down to a single specific problem, not "I need this task done what's the answer?"

Comment: Although I will give you a hint, you can replace `<iframe>` with `<object>`. and `src=` with `data=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `<object>` to display a video. Using `<object>` for videos is an outdated approach. Use `<video>` instead

```html
 <video controls>
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

if you really want to use `<object>`

```html
 <object data="video.mp4"></object>
```

Of course, all of this assumes you have the video downloaded. If you want to display the youtube video directly from the youtube link like your example, you will have to just embed the youtube player in your webpage with an iframe. You cannot access the raw video directly from youtube.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSM3w1v-A_Y">
```

EDIT: For clarification, you can link to a video from another source, but YouTube does not expose the raw video itself so this is not applicable to YouTube. Also, you can technically put the YouTube link directly in an `<object>` as you described, but this will cause a CORS violation and therefore will not load. This also still essentially just embeds the youtube player

Comment: You can use `<video>` and `<object>` tags with sources on other websites as long as the CORS policy allows it, which in this case YouTube's does (hence why you can also use an iframe)